# Are memory variables initialized by solidity?

Tags: solidity, struct

I've the following struct

```
struct Vote {
  uint amount;
  uint count;
}
```

Is it initialized when allocated in memory?

```
function boofar(uint val) public {
  Vote memory result;
  result.amount += val;
}
```

When explicitly initialized the gas cost is higher 1481 vs 1417.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They will be assigned zero values corresponding to type.

```
bool: false
uint: 0
int: 0
string: length 0
array: length 0
bytes: length 0
mapping: prohibited as memory variable
```

So, if you say `result = ({ amount: 0, count: 0 });` you will create the same initial state at the cost of some useless work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it documented this behavior? I found in the docs that I should not expect the free memory to be zeroed https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/miscellaneous.html#layout-in-memory. In the warning it says _The memory may or may not be zeroed out._

Comment: hmmm ... I've never seen not work as expected but that casts some doubt on things. The question just got interesting.

Comment: Looking at the byte code the Solidity compiler emits, I'm pretty sure Solidity explicitly initializes the memory to 0. The warning in the documentation seems to be about directly manipulating memory yourself (where Solidity isn't doing any initialization).

Comment: Thanks. That was my interpretation of the doc as well and yet the way it is worded left me with doubt.

Comment: @smarx I think your comment is the right answer I was looking for. It should be good to update solidity docs to clarify this.